# Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class - Extend System.Delegate?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, extension-methods

This is in reference to the code examples in the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596516109-03-09.aspx

The C# compiler expects that the `EveryOther()` method be defined in it's own static class.

Do I need to extend `System.Delegate` with a new method `EveryOther()`?

```
namespace DelegateTest
{    
    public class TestInvokeIntReturn
    {
        public static int Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method1");
            return 1;
        }

        public static int Method2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method2");
            return 2;
        }

        public static int Method3()
        {
            //throw (new Exception("Method1"));
            //throw (new SecurityException("Method3"));
            Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method3");
            return 3;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int> myDelegateInstance1 = TestInvokeIntReturn.Method1;
            Func<int> myDelegateInstance2 = TestInvokeIntReturn.Method2;
            Func<int> myDelegateInstance3 = TestInvokeIntReturn.Method3;

            Func<int> allInstances = //myDelegateInstance1;
                    myDelegateInstance1 +
                    myDelegateInstance2 +
                    myDelegateInstance3;

            Delegate[] delegateList = allInstances.GetInvocationList();
            Console.WriteLine("Invoke every other delegate");
            foreach (Func<int> instance in delegateList.EveryOther())
            {
                // invoke the delegate
                int retVal = instance();
                Console.WriteLine("Delegate returned " + retVal);
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            bool retNext = true;
            foreach (T t in enumerable)
            {
                if (retNext) yield return t;
                retNext = !retNext;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `EveryOther` as an extension method you'll have to put it in a static class:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        bool retNext = true;
        foreach (T t in enumerable)
        {
            if (retNext) yield return t;
            retNext = !retNext;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use it as an extension method, you could change the signature of `EveryOther` to

```
static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
```

and then simply call `EveryOther(delegateList)` instead of `delegateList.EveryOther()`.